# Azure Devops Split String function

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm having trouble in an azure devops pipeline.

$(Build.SourceBranch) outputs something like `refs/heads/xyz`

I'd like to use something like JavaScript's `.split('/')` to output an array at the slashes.

Meaning `$b = $(Build.SourceBranch).Split('/')` would output

```
$b[0] = "refs"
$b[1] = "heads"
$b[2] = "xyz"
```

I'm not finding much on how I can do this easily.

Comment: If you need only the branchname you could use `$(Build.SourceBranchName)`

Comment: Have you tried using the YAML function from this link (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-support-for-string-split-function-in-yaml-expr/1302414) ? `split(variables.str, ',')` but changing the symbol to `/` as you want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Azure Pipeline, you can use PowerShell script to split string.

From your script, you need to add double quotes around the variable:$(Build.SourceBranch) to make it a string first and then split it.

Here is an example:

```
- powershell: |
   
   $b = "$(Build.SourceBranch)".Split("/")
   
   $b[0]
   $b[1]
   $b[2]
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: You should be able to export values using `##vso[task.setvariable variable=B_0]%$b[0]%` - you might need to play around with it, but should get you most of the way there. You can then reference the variable later user `$(B_0)`.